# Is it possible to persist data without using localStorage or other types of storage?

Tags: next.js, local-storage, react-query

I am having a hard time to persist a data without using local storage since I know that local storage is not really secured to store the user's details.

May I know if I can persist a data without using localstorage and can I use react query to persist a data?

Comment: There is `SessionStorage`, it's a bit like `LocaleStorage` so keeps data between browser refreshes, but when the user closes the Tab/Window the data is lost.  Also when you say `really secured`, it depends on what you mean here, eg. If someone has direct access to your device, then pretty much nothing is secure on a PC.  Details on your use case might help determine if this is a none issue using `LocaleStorage` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to persist data without using localstorage or client side solution.

You should setup an API endpoint for your next.js app to handle data storage and retrieval. When a user submits data, you can make a request to the endpoint, which will then store the data in a secure manner, such a database.

Regarding React Query, it is primarily for managin and caching data in the client-side, but you can use it with server-side storage. You can react Query  to fetch data from your server and update the UI, while the actual data storage and retrieval happen on the server.

A simple example could be:

```js
import { useQuery, useMutation, queryCache } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const fetchData = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get("/api/data");
  return res.data;
};

const updateData = async (newData) => {
  const res = await axios.post("/api/data", newData);
  return res.data;
};

function HomePage() {
  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery("data", fetchData);

  const mutation = useMutation(saveData, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      // Invalidate / refetch the data when a mutation is success
      queryCache.invalidateQueries('data');
    },
  });

  const handleSave = (newData) => {
    mutation.mutate(newData);
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Load...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Data: {data}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => handleSave("new data")}>Save Data</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

`fetchData`: makes a request to the API endpoint to retrive informations.
`saveData`: makes a request to update the data.

Comment: If that is the case then how to avoid re-fetching the data for every route to maintain and display the user details in the browser?

because mine I tried to putting useeffect for every route to just re-fetch and maintain the data but it can potentially affect the performance of my system.

Comment: to avoid refetching every time (mainly for cost / performance purpose) you have 2 options:
1. Global State Managment: use a library like redux, zustand to make data persists across different pages
2. Context API: use react context api to create a context for storing and accessing the user details.
both solution allows you to share the state across components without prop drilling

Comment: I already tried it and I used zustand but the problem is when the user refresh the page, the user details is resetting or disappear in the page, so need it again to refetch.

Comment: yes, and thats normal. user should not refresh the page if not needed.